# Plone: switch off document_byline (creation info)

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have two mostly similar Plone sites; on one the `document_view` shows author and creation date information below the document title, on the other it doesn't.  I figured out that this information comes from the `DocumentBylineViewlet` (as I verified by writing the filename in `plone.app.layout-2.3.11-py2.7.egg/plone/app/layout/viewlets/document_byline.pt`), and that there is a `allow_anon_views_about` setting in the `@@security-controlpanel`.

However, I'd like to omit that information even for most authenticated users; e.g., even for logged in users, the "created by" and "last changed" information for the contact page is not interesting.
(It is mainly an optical problem; no problem with me if the information would still be somewhere in the HTML head.)

I found the viewlet to be constrained by the `zope2.View` permission.
I could imagine to use another permission which I could map to a certain role, e.g. to show such information only to users who are allowed to apply changes themselves.

Is there a suggested permission to use, and how would I configure my system to use it?  Or is there a better, and completely different way?

(The only other way I found is to hide the `.documentByLine` element by CSS ...)

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @tcurvelo is ok if you whant to hide all of the elements of the byline.

If not: installing [rt.lastmodifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rt.lastmodifier) will give you superpowers about who can see single items in the byline.
Check the documentation.

Comment: Yippieh, exactly what I was looking for: Have last modifier *and* creator in the byline. The permission-settings-option is the cherry on top, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the `plone.belowcontenttitle.documentbyline` viewlet TTW in the `@@manage-viewlets` or, if you please,  permanently in a `viewlets.xml` file.

Comment: That's interesting. On my `plone_control_panel` page this doesn't seem to be linked. I don't have found any control there to *hide* a viewlet (only to move them), possibly caused by style problems.

Comment: @Tobias: yes, I think the link to hide a viewlet is given the `hide` css class, which easily clashes. You can find it with the browser's dev tools, though. (I haven't checked if giving you the link format still works with the latest security patches.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the template that is used in the ZMI via `(yoursite)/portal_view_customizations/registrations.html`, it's listed way down under `zope.interface.Interface`.

In the easiest case, you'd take the

```
<div class="documentByLine"
     id="plone-document-byline"
     i18n:domain="plone"
     tal:condition="view/show">
```

at the top (`view/show` calls code that evaluates the flag you mention), and replace the `tal:condition="view/show"` with

```
tal:condition="python: context.portal_membership.checkPermission('cmf.ReviewPortalContent', self.context)"
```

or similar. The Plone docs have a (partial) [list of permissions](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/security/standard_permissions.html). I've used "Review portal content" as an example, because it's conveniently tied to the Reviewer role, which in my day-job installation isn't used for anything useful.

Comment: The `Review portal content` permission looks reasonable; I have mapped it to the `Manager` and `Reviewer` roles. I'm not entirely sure it works right; a user who is a member of the `Reviewers` group which grants the local `Reviewer` role doesn't have the portlet for his own content.

Comment: This solution suits me in allowing to adjust the used permission; the drawback is, it involves a copy of the whole viewlet which won't get updated when `plone.app.layout` is updated ...